Spring Boot 3, OAuth2 Flow, Custom Login, Redirect after first failed login attempt
I have a working Spring Boot 3 OAuth2 flow. When users try to log in to my client application, they are correctly redirected to the login page of my authorization server. After providing the correct credentials, they are redirected back to the original client, and everything works as expected.
However, I'm facing an issue when users enter incorrect credentials on their first login attempt. They are redirected to the login page with an appropriate error message. But when they then try to log in again with the correct credentials, they are not redirected back to the client. Instead, they remain logged into the authorization server itself. This behavior is unexpected since users should be redirected back to the client they originally attempted to access.
Authorization Server Configuration:
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Profile(value = {"development", "production"})
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig {

  private final SecurityApp app;

  public OAuth2SecurityConfig(SecurityApp app) {
    this.app = app;
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(3)
  public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
        .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());  // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
    http.exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/security.html?content=login")));
    return http.build();
  }

  // Other beans (OAuth2TokenCustomizer, RegisteredClientRepository, etc.) omitted for brevity
}

Login Configuration:
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Profile(value = {"development", "production"})
public class AppSecurityConfig {

  private final SecurityApp app;

  public AppSecurityConfig(SecurityApp app) {
    this.app = app;
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    HttpSessionRequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
    MfaAuthenticationHandler mfaAuthenticationHandler = new MfaAuthenticationHandler("/security.html?content=otp&error=false", app);

    http.securityMatcher(request -> {
          final String url = request.getServletPath() + StringUtils.defaultString(request.getPathInfo());
          log.debug("Checking if form login is responsible for this URL: {}", url);
          return !url.startsWith("/rest/api/")
              && !url.startsWith("/rest/cas/")
              && !url.startsWith("/oauth2/")
              && !url.startsWith("/userinfo");
        })
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/security/account/**", "/security.html**", "/locales/*", "ucan.png", "/favicon.ico",
                             "/ucan.png", "/requestPassword.html", "/secondFactor.html", "/resetPassword.html",
                             "/login.html", "/footer.html", "/rest/oauth2/requestPasswordReset", "login.css",
                             "/security/account/requestPasswordReset", "/security/account/resetPassword",
                             "/perform_login", "/oauth/**", "/login").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/security/flow/**").access(mfaAuthorizationManager())
            .requestMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/generatedFiles/**", "/rest/app/**",
                             "/desktop/**", "/app/**", "/node_modules/**", "/build/**", "/resources/**",
                             "/app.js", "/froalaeditor.pkgd.css**").authenticated())
        .formLogin(form -> form
            .loginPage("/security.html?content=login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            .successHandler(mfaAuthenticationHandler)
            .failureHandler(mfaAuthenticationHandler)
            .permitAll())
        .logout(logout -> logout
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/security.html?content=login&logout=true")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll())
        .requestCache(cache -> cache.requestCache(requestCache))
        .headers(headers -> headers
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-hashes' 'unsafe-eval'; " +
                                   "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:"))
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    return http.build();
  }

  // Other beans (mfaAuthorizationManager, successHandler, failureHandler, etc.) omitted for brevity
}

MfaAuthenticationHandler:
public class MfaAuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandler {

  private final AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
  private final SecurityApp app;
  private final SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository = new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();

  public MfaAuthenticationHandler(String url, SecurityApp app) {
    this.app = app;
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler(url);
    successHandler.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true);
    this.successHandler = successHandler;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                      AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/security.html?content=login&error=login");
  }

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                      Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    saveMfaAuthentication(request, response, authentication);
  }

  private void saveMfaAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                     Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    CusSecurityPrincipal user = (CusSecurityPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();

    if (!user.getAuthType().equals(AuthType.PASSWORD)) {
      if (user.getAuthType().equals(AuthType.EMAIL)) {
        String code = app.random6Digits();
        user.setSecret(code);
        app.sendTokenMail(user.getUsername(), code);
      }
      context.setAuthentication(new MfaAuthentication(authentication));
      this.securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response);
      this.successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    } else {
      context.setAuthentication(authentication);
      this.securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response);
      app.onAuthenticationSuccess(authentication.getName());

      // Handle redirection after successful login
      new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler().onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
  }
}

I suspect the issue might lie in my MfaAuthenticationHandler, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any guidance on how to ensure users are redirected back to their original client after a failed login attempt would be greatly appreciated.
